# How to build OpenCV for both python versions 2 and 3?

Tags: python, linux, opencv, build, cmake

In [OpenCV linux install doc](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html), section `Building OpenCV from Source Using CMake` it is said to run command like

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```

Simultaneously, there are given parameters for python:

```
[optional] Building python. Set the following python parameters:
PYTHON2(3)_EXECUTABLE = <path to python>
PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR = /usr/include/python<version>
PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR2 = /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python<version>
PYTHON_LIBRARY = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython<version>.so
PYTHON2(3)_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS = /usr/lib/python<version>/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/
```

Some of these parameters can easily be set for both version of Python:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D PYTHON2_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3  ..
```

but another ones are ambiguous

```
PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR = /usr/include/python<version>
```

Is it possible to build for both versions of Python at once?

Comment: You might want to have a look at `cmake/OpenCVDetectPython.cmake`... near the bottom. There are two complete sets of those variables, one prefixed with `PYTHON2` and other with `PYTHON3`. (e.g. I see both `PYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR` and `PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR` there).

Comment: @DanMašek where is it, don't see?

Comment: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/cmake/OpenCVDetectPython.cmake#L225

Comment: What is it? I have Python 3.5

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend this [guide](http://www.python36.com/how-to-install-opencv340-on-ubuntu1604/) as an install reference.

But in general all you have to do is to install both versions of python and then run the install script. There is no need to manually specify python paths, cmake will find them.

Attached screenshot with recent OpenCV install output:
[image: terminal screenshot, python paths]

Answer (score 2):

As of December 2018, I was able to compile the latest OpenCV version in my Ubuntu16.04 machine with CUDA, FFMpeg and TIFF (useful to work with Caffe too), and to run it in both Python2.7 and 3.5. The build was highly inspired in [this post](https://www.cerebrumedge.com/single-post/2017/12/26/Compiling-OpenCV-with-CUDA-and-FFMpeg-on-Ubuntu-1604), so kudos to them!

### Clone the latest repos:

Note that **both** have to be in the same release otherwise cmake will complain. Make sure to clone both at the same time:

```
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git
```

### Configure and build:

First, create the standard build environment:

```
cd opencv
mkdir build
cd build
```

Then, the following cmake command worked for me:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
             -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
             -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
             -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=<LOCATION_OF_YOUR_OPENCV_CONTRIB>/modules \
             -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \
             -D BUILD_opencv_python2=ON \
             -D WITH_FFMPEG=1 \
             -D WITH_TIFF=ON \
             -D WITH_CUDA=ON \
             -D CUDA_GENERATION=Pascal \
             -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 \
             -D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 \
             -D WITH_CUBLAS=1 \
             -D WITH_LAPACK=OFF \
             -D PYTHON2_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python \
             -D PYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python2.7 \
             -D PYTHON2_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so \
             -D PYTHON2_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include \
             -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 \
             -D PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.5 \
             -D PYTHON3_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so \
             -D PYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include \
             -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

Note that you have to set the `<LOCATION_OF_YOUR_OPENCV_CONTRIB>` (the place where you cloned it), and you may have to adapt your `PYTHON2`and `PYTHON3`flags to your system's disposition.

I got some warnings (not sure how bad that is), but it went through: after a while you should see something like

```
--   Install to:                    /usr/local
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring done
```

### Make and install

Again, the standard `make -j<NUM_CORES> && sudo make install` works here. Make sure to adjust `-j` to your number of CPU cores to speed up the compilation process. After that, the python command

```
import cv2
```

worked both in Python 2 and 3. Hope this helps!
Andres

Answer (score 0):

No, bindings to binary modules (compiled from C) are different in Python 2 and Python 3. The same built libs cannot be used from Python 2 and Python 3.

But you may run build instructions for Python 2, then Python 3 using distinct CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX values.

Comment: @Dims, yes but it seems there is no other solution. Python modules compiled from C cannot work for both Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: Isn't it possible to have two sets of python modules only, leaving all other code shared?

Comment: @Dims "Yes" but this would involve lots of bug prone custom changes in the source bundle (do it yourself). Personally, I prefer to lose some Mbs in cheap hard drives than losing days of work for uncertain earnings.